# Threejs: Differences between geometry.faceVertexUvs in r47 and geometry.faceVertexUvs in r58

Tags: canvas, maps, three.js, webgl, textures

Working on a part of code porting from threejs r47 to threejs r58. I have problems with canvas 2d texture where the loaded[image] image is stretched.

The respective code snippet follows:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 80, 60 );
for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].length; i < l; i ++ ) {
    for ( var j = 0, jl = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ i ].length; j < jl; j ++ ) {
        var uv = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ i ][ j ];
        var a = uv.v * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;
        a = Math.sin(a);
        uv.v = 0.5 - Math.log( ( 1 + a ) / ( 1 - a ) ) / ( 4 * Math.PI );
        uv.v = 1 - uv.v;
    }
}
```

I think, there are some changes in the way geometry.faceVertexUvs are used from Threejs r47 to r58. Any help, warmly welcomed!. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration

"UV replaced with Vector2. This means .u and .v are now .x and .y."
from r53 to r54. Maybe this helps? :)